Aspire.Hosting.Dcp. the program finished with an error[0]
I am trying to get Aspire up and running with the new dotnet 9. But I get the following error on startup

Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.the program finished with an error[0]
{"ExitCode": 1, "error": "could not determine installed DCP extensions: CreateFile C:\Users\%username%\.dcp\ext: The system cannot find the file specified."}

Whatever ProjectTemplate I'm using I see this same error at startup
Currently working with the Aspire StarterTemplate
var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var apiService = builder.AddProject<Projects.AspireStarter_ApiService>("apiservice");

builder.AddProject<Projects.AspireStarter_Web>("webfrontend")
    .WithExternalHttpEndpoints()
    .WithReference(apiService)
    .WaitFor(apiService);

builder.Build().Run();

I tried uninstall and install docker desktop
Before re-installing windows on my laptop I was hoping to get any help. Thank you in advance

Is there a global.json that forces .NET 8? What does dotnet --version show? In .NET 9 Aspire comes as templates instead of a workload. Have you tried creating a new starter project in an unrelated clean folder?

dotnet --version 9.0.100 and there is no global.json. The problem occurs when creating a new starter project in a clean folder

Have you set Docker to use Linux or Windows containers?  If you call dotnet run in the AppHost folder all the services should come up. Docker isn't involved at this point. And even if you start with Docker, the images are based on Linux and won't use Windows paths.
